# Searching for Contacts in ActiveDirectory (.NET)

Tags: .net, active-directory

I have an application where I need to pull contacts from Active Directory.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
Public Function GetADContacts(ByVal LastNameStarts As String) As DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection
    Dim rootDSE As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Dim defaultNamingContext As String = rootDSE.Properties("defaultNamingContext").Value.ToString()
    Dim objSearch As New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher()
    Dim cllQueryResults As DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection

    With objSearch
        .SearchRoot = New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + defaultNamingContext)
        .Filter = "(&(objectclass=contact)(mailNickname=*)(cn=*)(sn=" + LastNameStarts + "*)(givenname=*))"
        .SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree
        .PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(New String() {"cn", "sn", "givenname", "mailNickname"})
        .Sort.PropertyName = "sn"
        .Sort.Direction = DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending
        cllQueryResults = .FindAll()
    End With

    Return cllQueryResults
End Function
```

I've checked to make sure the contacts have sn, cn, givenname, and mailNickname attributes set, but nothing is returned.  When I change the objectcategory to user, I get all the users, but for contacts, I get nothing.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for contacts only your filter should look like this:

```
Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=contact))"
```

Here a little example to get the DN of all contacts:

```
Dim Searcher As New DirectorySearcher("LDAP://")
Dim QueryResults As SearchResultCollection
Dim Result As SearchResult

Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")
Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=contact))"

QueryResults = Searcher.FindAll

For Each Result In QueryResults
    Console.WriteLine(Result.Properties("distinguishedName")(0))
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

There is a very helpful article on this topic: [Active Directory: LDAP Filter Syntax](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx).   <s>Sadly I dind't save the link.. I'll try to provide it later.</s>